# LiveAgent Chat button on the footer of Napili Template

Tags: liveagent, customer-community, community-builder

I'm trying to add a liveAgent chat button on a customer community, when I add the button on the footer of the napili template liveAgent seems to lose track of the button and doesn't update according to agents online/offline status.
The button is correctly placed and initialized, but the request to check availability is never made.
If I place the button on another part of this template it works as expected, thats why I think the problem is not the implementation I made. I'm also checking the JavaScript console and there are not errors thrown.

has anyone been able to add a button like this on the footer of the template?
 thanks

Answer (score 1):

the problem was that buttons in the napili template took longer to render when they were placed in the footer.
I updated the logic which controlled the live agent initializations and the buttons began to work as expected.
sorry the confusion!

Comment: I have the same problem, can you,please, share a snippet of your code, I want to to understand what's going on

Comment: could you please post the code......I am also facing the same issue